# Ionic2/3 angular google maps TypeError: Object(...) is not a function at new FitBoundsService

Tags: android, angular, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to instantiate an angular-google-maps example from the main website: https://angular-maps.com/guides/getting-started/ to make some tests for an aplication.

I used their example code as it follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        @Component({
              selector: 'page-location',
              templateUrl: 'location.html',

            })
            export class LocationPage {
              title: string = 'My first AGM project';
              lat: number = 51.678418;
              lng: number = 7.809007;
}



page-location 
{

    agm-map {
  height: 150px;
}

}



<h1>{{ title }}</h1>

<!-- this creates a google map on the page with the given lat/lng from -->
<!-- the component as the initial center of the map: -->
<agm-map style="height: 300px;" [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
  <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

And in the end throws the following error:

> core.js:1449 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   Object(...) is not a function TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at new FitBoundsService (fit-bounds.js:31)
>       at createClass (core.js:12481)
>       at _createProviderInstance (core.js:12458)
>       at createProviderInstance (core.js:12299)
>       at createViewNodes (core.js:13771)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:14218)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
>       at createViewNodes (core.js:13812)
>       at createRootView (core.js:13673)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
>       at new FitBoundsService (fit-bounds.js:31)
>       at createClass (core.js:12481)
>       at _createProviderInstance (core.js:12458)
>       at createProviderInstance (core.js:12299)
>       at createViewNodes (core.js:13771)
>       at callViewAction (core.js:14218)
>       at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14127)
>       at createViewNodes (core.js:13812)
>       at createRootView (core.js:13673)
>       at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
>       at c (polyfills.js:3)
>       at Object.reject (polyfills.js:3)
>       at OverlayPortal.NavControllerBase._fireError (nav-controller-base.js:223)
>       at OverlayPortal.NavControllerBase._failed (nav-controller-base.js:216)
>       at nav-controller-base.js:263
>       at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.js:4760)
>       at t.invoke (polyfills.js:3)
>       at r.run (polyfills.js:3)
>       at polyfills.js:3
>
> I would appreciate your help to look for the source of this problem.

Comment: If you are a beginner in ionic than can follow this article URL: https://www.joshmorony.com/ionic-2-how-to-use-google-maps-geolocation-video-tutorial/

Answer (score 5):

I added the following command `npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save` and it work fine for me.

Comment: Hey, this solved it for me too!!! I was previously seeing the error. Now I can see the map. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @SANAAbdoulAziz Can you please explain me, What is the conenction between agm-map to rxjs and rxjs-compat ?

Answer (score 2):

This could be a packaging version dependency issue with @agm/core & angular.

Try lower your "@agm/core" version in your package.json for your project (I've used 1.0.0-beta.2, instead of the installed 1.0.0-beta.5).

They've introduced a breaking change: [feat(*): support angular 6](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/commit/fa1ecba773c54cbe65cf26401ab10be8aa4a783a)

Answer (score 0):

for me resolved when used version: 1.0.0-beta.3

package.json:

```
"@agm/core": "~1.0.0-beta.3"
```